# How to generate SWT table Dynamic drop down in Excel Sheet?

Tags: apache-poi, swt

I want to generate dynamic drop down at SWT column that column as well as excel sheet.

SWT same table column as well as excell column order are same.

Answer (score 0):

This is code for it. 
I have convert SWT Table into Excel Table with validation and protected sheet.

SWTTableMain.java:- main class.

```
public class SWTTableMain extends Shell {
private Table table;
public static final String[] ITEMS = { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" };

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        SWTTableMain shell = new SWTTableMain(display);
        // tableShell = display.getActiveShell();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public SWTTableMain(final Display display) {
    super(display, SWT.SHELL_TRIM);
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Button btnOpenexcel = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
    btnOpenexcel.setText("OpenExcel");

    table = new Table(this, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
    table.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    TableColumn tblclmnSrNo = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnSrNo.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnSrNo.setText("SR No:");
    tblclmnSrNo.setMoveable(true);
    TableColumn tblclmnName = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnName.setWidth(138);
    tblclmnName.setText("Name");
    tblclmnName.setMoveable(true);

    TableColumn tblclmnNewColumn = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnNewColumn.setWidth(119);
    tblclmnNewColumn.setText("Address");
    tblclmnNewColumn.setMoveable(true);
    TableColumn tblclmnEmail = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnEmail.setWidth(122);
    tblclmnEmail.setText("Email");
    tblclmnEmail.setMoveable(true);

    TableColumn tblclmnDropdown = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
    tblclmnDropdown.setWidth(100);
    tblclmnDropdown.setText("DropDown");
    tblclmnDropdown.setMoveable(true);

    // fill table data
    TableItem item1 = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
    item1.setText(new String[] { "1", "Test1", "Ahemdabad", "xyz@gmail.com" });
    TableEditor editor = new TableEditor(table);
    CCombo combo = new CCombo(table, SWT.NONE);
    combo.setText("Select");
    combo.setItems(ITEMS);
    editor.grabHorizontal = true;
    editor.setEditor(combo, item1, 4);

    // Write data to xls
    btnOpenexcel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ExcelSheet.generateExcelSheet(table, ITEMS);
            ExcelDialog excelDialog = new ExcelDialog(display.getActiveShell(), SWT.NONE);
            excelDialog.open();
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    createContents();
}


protected void createContents() {
    setText("SWT Application");
    setSize(597, 300);
    }
```

}

ExcelSheet.java

```
  public class ExcelSheet {
private static String[] DropdownValue = null;
static DataValidation dataValidation = null;
static DataValidationConstraint constraint = null;
static DataValidationHelper validationHelper = null;

public static void generateExcelSheet(final Table table, String[] ITEMS) {

    try {

        // For file read
        InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("D:\\XLTest\\ExportedData.xlsx");
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);
        // add a worksheet

        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);     
        cleanSheet(sheet);
        wb.lockStructure();// locak wrokbbok
        validationHelper = new XSSFDataValidationHelper(sheet);
        // shade the background of the header row
        XSSFCellStyle headerStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
        headerStyle.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.LEMON_CHIFFON.getIndex());
        // add header row
        TableColumn[] columns = table.getColumns();
        // add data rows
        TableItem[] items = table.getItems();
        int[] Colorder = table.getColumnOrder();
        int rowIndex = 0;
        int cellIndex = 0;
        int DropDownColOrder = 0;
        XSSFRow header = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex++);


        for(int i= 0;i< Colorder.length; i++)
        {
            XSSFCell cell = header.createCell(cellIndex++);
            cell.setCellValue(columns[Colorder[i]].getText());
            System.out.println("Heder Value:-"+columns[Colorder[i]].getText());

            if(columns[Colorder[i]].getText().equals("DropDown")){
                System.out.println("i:-"+i);
                DropDownColOrder = i;


            }
            cell.setCellStyle(headerStyle);
        }


        DropdownValue = ITEMS;      
        constraint = validationHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(DropdownValue);
        int lastRow = table.getItemCount();
        CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(1,lastRow, DropDownColOrder, DropDownColOrder);
        dataValidation = validationHelper.createValidation(constraint,addressList);
        dataValidation.setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
        sheet.addValidationData(dataValidation);

        for (TableItem item : items) {
            // create a new row
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) rowIndex++);              
            if(row != null)
            {
                cellIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++)
                {
                  // create a new cell
                    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
                    // set the horizontal alignment (default to RIGHT)                      
                    XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
                    cellStyle.setLocked(true);                  
                    cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);       
                    cell.setCellValue(item.getText(Colorder[cellIndex]));
                    cellIndex++;
                }
             }

        }       


        // autofit the columns
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) i);
        }
        String filename = "D:\\XLTest\\ExportedData.xlsx";
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
        wb.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        MessageDialog.openInformation(new Shell(),"Save Workbook Successful","Workbook saved to the file:\n\n" + filename);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        String msg = ioe.getMessage();
        MessageDialog.openError(new Shell(), "Save Workbook Failed","Could not save workbook to the file:\n\n" + msg);
    }

}

public static boolean cleanSheet(XSSFSheet sheet) {
    int numberOfRows =  sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

    if(numberOfRows > 0) {
         sheet.getCTWorksheet().unsetDataValidations();
        for (int i =  sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <=  sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            if( sheet.getRow(i) != null) {
                 sheet.removeRow(sheet.getRow(i));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Info: clean sheet='" +  sheet.getSheetName() + "' ... skip line: " + i);
            }
        }     
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Info: clean sheet='" +  sheet.getSheetName() + "' ... is empty");
    }
    return false;       
}
```

}

ExcelDialog.java

```
 public class ExcelDialog extends Dialog {

protected Object result,tabledata;
protected Shell shell;
private OleFrame oleframe = null;
private OleClientSite oleClientSite = null;

private String fileLocation = "D:\\XLTest\\ExportedData.xlsx";


public ExcelDialog(Shell parent, int style) {
    super(parent, style);
    setText("SWT Dialog");
}


public Object open() {
    createContents();
    shell.open();
    shell.setMaximized(true);
    shell.layout();
    Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private void openCurrentDataSheet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("called");
    oleframe = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
    oleframe.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1)); 
    oleClientSite = new OleClientSite(oleframe, SWT.NONE, "Excel.Sheet",new File(fileLocation)); 
    oleClientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);


}


private void createContents() {
    shell = new Shell(getParent(), SWT.SHELL_TRIM | SWT.BORDER);
    shell.setSize(450, 300);
    shell.setText(getText());
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));              
        openCurrentDataSheet();     
        Button btnSave = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
        btnSave.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
        btnSave.setText("Save");

        btnSave.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {              
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("click event called");

                // File is aleredy located or not
                 File xlsFile = new File(fileLocation); 
                 boolean fileAvilable = xlsFile.exists();
                 System.out.println("fileAvilable:--"+fileAvilable);

            if(fileAvilable == true)
            {
                boolean filedeleted = xlsFile.delete();
                System.out.println("filedeleted:--"+filedeleted);
                File finalFile = new File(fileLocation);
                oleClientSite.save(finalFile, true);
                oleClientSite.deactivateInPlaceClient();
                shell.dispose();
                System.out.println("file new Saved");
            }   
            }

        @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });         
}
```

}